# SVG tooltip hide/show

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have problem with SVG and jQuery. I have hidden part of the SVG with a CSS class, and have another class that shows it. I want a function which makes this part visible or hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/tj3xLazc/

```js
$('.scientist').on(click,function(){
     $('#toltip').removeClass('dont-speak');
     addClass = "speak";
})
```

Comment: can you update your fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tj3xLazc/

Comment: can you please explain when you want to show and hide tooltip?

Comment: you see illustration without tooltip coz in class i have display: none;
and i want to change onclick this visibility. sry for my english

Answer (score 1):

use below code . check [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tj3xLazc/1/)

in your fiddle you forgot to include jquery lib. jquery not support class with SVG. instead of add/remove class use attr().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.scientist').on('click',function(){
   if( $('#toltip').attr('class') === 'dont-speak'){
    $('#toltip').attr('class','speak');
   }else{
   $('#toltip').attr('class','dont-speak');
   }
 });
});
```